# multiple api calls in vue and each using info. fetched from previous call

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I am making API calls to fetch data and then info fetched from the prevoious call is to be used to make another API call.
in boardid i am providing board id

```
   methods: {
     async getdata() {
response2 =await axios.get('https://api.trello.com/1/boards/boardid/cards?fields=all&key=keyid&token=tokenid')
vm.response = response2.data; 
for(let i = 0; i <5; i++){
vm.cardlink = response2.data[i].shortLink;
vm.cardid = response2.data[i].id;
vm.arr.push(vm.cardlink);
response3 =  await axios.get("https://api.trello.com/1/cards/"+vm.cardid+"/attachments?feilds=all&key=keyid&token=tokenid")
vm.name = response3.data[0].name;
console.log(response3);
vm.arr.push(vm.name);
  }
  }
  }

----------
<div id="app">  
<div v-for="img in arr">    
<img :src="'https:/y/library/'+arr[0]+'/'+arr[1]" style="width:250px"/>
</div>
</div>
```

i am getting the same image 10 times. how do i iterate in that array. for getting other images.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: What made you use `vm` internal variable  ? Also what's the problem you are facing ?

Comment: that problem i solved

Comment: @SatyamPathak i have updated the question now i am able to do do multiple api calls. The problem is i am not able to iterate in the array, how do i loop in that